# /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:8:in `require': cannot load such file -- debase (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:8:in `require': cannot load such file -- debase (LoadError)
```

I am getting this error when trying to run the rails server on Mac OSX mavericks. I am using the Aptana studio 3 to debug and the set up is causing this issue

Gem file includes ruby-debu-ide gem:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
```

Comment: yes I did. bundle is working fine.

Comment: try explicitly adding the version, e.g. `gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '0.4.22'`

Comment: Boris, I did that. Still having the same problem.

Comment: Looking at the [sources](https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-ide/blob/master/Gemfile), `ruby-debug-ide` only installs `ruby-debug-base` for 1.8 or 1.9; it seems to not install anything nothing for 2.0. However, [here](https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-ide/blob/master/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb) it uses `debase` on 2.0. Can you try sticking `gem "debase"` manually into your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Thanks Amadan...It resolved the issue. However when I put a debug breakpoint on apatana studio 3 in a controller and run "rails s" and try to access the controller thru a browser...It does not stop at my breakpoint in the controller...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that debase is available and can be found.

Look at the output from "gem list", and whether it includes debase.

Then make sure that it really is in the respective directory where it ought to be - as you use a .rvm directory, it must be in the same directory of your ruby version, e .g. for me it is at PREFIX/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/